# How to get geckodriver log info

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

selenium webdriver: v3.5.3
geckodriver: 0.19
firefox: v55

Hi all, im currently learning to automate using Java/selenium.
Im using selenium 3.5.3 and geckodriver to try and automate the Firefox browser and I am experiencing errors when trying to automate the Firefox driver. I created a ticket on [github](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/956) and subsequently was asked to provide a gecko driver log.

As a rank beginner im unsure of how i actually do this....

More specifically how would i specifiy moz:firefoxOptions in order to get the geckodriver log info?

This is an example taken from the read me file

```
{
    "capabilities": {
        "alwaysMatch": {
            "moz:firefoxOptions": {
                "binary": "/usr/local/firefox/bin/firefox",
                "args": ["-headless", "-profile", "/path/to/my/profile"],
                "prefs": {
                    "dom.ipc.processCount": 8
                },
                "log": {
                    "level": "trace"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

There doesnt seem to be an explanation on the readme as to where I need to add the above content in order to get the log information  hence don’t understand what I need to do in order to generate/view the geckodriver log info.

Ive tried updating this content and adding it to my code but that doesn’t work so I’m guessing its either incorrect or needs to be added somewhere else

Is anyone able to provide some simple steps instructing me on what I need to do and where i should do it in order to get the log info that I require?
Many thanks

Comment: Can you show us your code trials & research please?